# Ubuntu 18.10 - problem with installation of Radeon Software 18.40

Tags: drivers, apt, 18.10, amd-graphics

I downloaded and I am trying to install the latest AMD driver on Ubuntu 18.10, but in the process I get the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-sAIsfk/00-amdgpu-core_18.40-676022_all.deb
```

and the installation terminates.

In the official AMD specs I found that this driver is not supported for Ubuntu 18.10. Is there, however, a way to install it?

Without the AMDGPU driver Steam encounters running problems and produces errors similar to the following:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
```

Answer (score 0):

This should address the GL error:

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

If you want the latest AMD driver [which runs on 18.10](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then after a reboot you should be all set.

Comment: i have mesa from this ppa, but it not solve problem with Steam.

Comment: problem solved in another way. in oibaf repos need change in oibaf repos cosmic to bionic or use https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa bionic. i don`t know why cosmic repo haven`t all mesa files